# How to open a new window in flutter_inappwebview with about:blank

Tags: flutter, webview

I have a webpage that opens a new tab on browsers when I press print.It displays a receipt. The html is

```html
<button onclick="printInvoice(127)" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">print</button>
```

The problem is that the new window url is **"about:blank"** and when i tap on my flutter app it does nothing. I can't grab the html content as url is not valid. How to make it work like in a browser?

If I use this code, I get url is null

```dart
onCreateWindow: (controller, createWindowRequest) async {
  await controller.loadUrl(urlRequest: createWindowRequest.request);
  
  String newWindowContent = await controller.evaluateJavascript(
    source: 'document.documentElement.outerHTML;',
  );
  print('New Window Content: $newWindowContent');
  
  return true;
},
```